# Convert java object to xml?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xstream

I am using XStream for converting the java object to xml. But i am not getting the proper output. When i am iterating the object, I am able to get the information. But when that object is converted to xml by XStream, the data changes. I dont know what will be the problem.

Can you provide some alternate with some samples.

Thanks in advance. 
Easwar

Comment: can you post the code to reproduce, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: XStream normally works out of the box even if the XML isn't exactly what you expect. XStream creates an XML that it will be able to unmarshall with it's current configuration.

How does the object look and what is your output XML? How did you expect the output to look?

Answer (score 3):

[Castor Mapping](http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html). can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

Have you considered using a JAXB implementation (Metro, MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc)?  Here is an example of mapping the same object model with JAXB and XStream for comparison:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

In addition since JAXB is part of Java EE, it is the default binding layer for other Java EE technologies such as JAX-RS and JAX-WS:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

MOXy also contains some very useful extensions beyond the JAXB specification:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-multi-tenant.html